# Finding the phase and frequency of a tone with Doppler. What is wrong in the code?

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, frequency-spectrum, spectrum-estimation

I am trying to find the phase and frequency of a single tone having a small Doppler (10 Hz). I have the following code. The integration time for the operation (the length of the time vector) is defined in the code. It works if the integration time is a correct multiple otherwise not. Why is this failing?

Here is the code:

```
clearvars; close all; clc;

 Fc = 10.005e3;
 Fd = 10; % random doppler 
 Fc2 = Fc+Fd;
 phi = deg2rad(37.8);
 disp(['True Freq: ',num2str(Fc2),' Phi: ',num2str(rad2deg(phi))]);
 Fs = 1e6;      % Max. Sampling Freq allowed
 Ts = 1/Fs;     % Sampling interval
 T_intg = 1.2347e-3; % Max. Integration time allowed

 t  = 0:Ts:T_intg;                        % Time Vector
 s  = exp(1j*(t*2*pi*Fc2+phi));           % Signal Vector

 Fs = 1/Ts;                               % Sampling Frequency
 Fn = Fs/2;                               % Nyquist Frequency
 L  = length(s);

 fts = fft(s, L)/L;                       % Normalised Fourier Transform
 Fv = linspace(0, 1, fix(L/2)+1)*Fn;      % Frequency Vector
 Iv = 1:length(Fv);                       % Index Vector

 amp_fts = abs(fts(Iv))*2;                % Spectrum Amplitude
 phs_fts = angle(fts(Iv));                % Spectrum Phase

 [val, index] = max(amp_fts);             % locating the peak in the spectrum
 rad2deg(angle(fts(index)))                % this gives 104 instead of 37 degrees
```

Comment: @Richard ,so what's an appropriate method of finding the phase of a signal ?

Comment: Hi Raza. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344034/how-to-determine-phase-shift-of-a-sine-waveform

Answer (score 2):

Your FFT method of finding the phase of a single tone is only valid if your 's' signal contains an exact integer number of cycles. I.E., no spectral leakage. And that is NOT the case for your 's' signal.